# How Switzerland has significantly high cost of living as compared to its neighboring countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, basic-income, labor-cost, living-cost

Despite being a small country (area-wise), how Switzerland can sustain a high cost of living?

I get the logic that the pay of employees would be proportionally higher, so they can sustain a high cost of living. Not the entire country is mountainous, **at the least the cost of living should be comparable to neighboring countries especially in the plains.**

How does it be able to sustain the economy of border areas where people can do shopping in the neighboring countries?

Am I asking the right question? Clearly, there is some piece of the puzzle about Switzerland, that I don't get.